# Spring inject two implementations of an interface to use bridge design pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have implemented a sample of bridge design pattern in my application that uses Spring boot. I was wondering how I could manage to inject different implementations of an interface. Obviously, if I try to inject them it throws the `required a single bean, but 2 were found` I would appreciate it if you could help to understand how this can be achieved in conjunction with dependency injection:

Color.java

```
package com.example.bridge;

public interface Color {

  String fill();
}
```

Blue.java

```
package com.example.bridge;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("Blue")
public class Blue implements Color {
  @Override
  public String fill() {
    return "Color is Blue";
  }
}
```

Red.java

```
package com.example.bridge;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("Red")
public class Red implements Color {
  @Override
  public String fill() {
    return "Color is Red";
  }
}
```

Shape.java

```
package com.example.bridge;

public abstract class Shape {
  protected Color color;

  public Shape(Color color){
    this.color = color;
  }

  abstract public String draw();
}
```

Square.java

```
package com.example.bridge;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Square extends Shape {

  public Square(Color color) {
    super(color);
  }

  @Override
  public String draw() {
    return "Square drawn. " + color.fill();
  }
}
```

Triangle.java

```
package com.example.bridge;

@Service
public class Triangle extends Shape {

  public Triangle(Color color) {
    super(color);
  }

  @Override
  public String draw() {
    return "Triangle drawn. " + color.fill();
  }
}
```

BridgeApplication.java

```
package com.example.bridge;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example.bridge.*")
public class BridgeApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BridgeApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Test it:

```
package com.example.bridge;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestBridge {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("Red")
  private Red red;

  @Test
  public void testBridge() {
    //a square with red color
    Shape square = new Square(red);

    assertEquals(square.draw(), "Square drawn. Color is Red");
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

First, I have noticed I was missing 'componentScan' for the main class and after it's added now the application runs. However, the same approach is not applicable to the test. Whether I have got the component scan or not this is what I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.bridge.Red' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=Red)}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Qualifier` is the solution. Mark the `component` with `@Qualifier("unique-name") and when injecting the bean, use this qualifier.

```
@Service("blue")
public class Blue implements Color {
    @Override
    public String fill() {
        return "Color is Blue";
    }
}

@Service("red")
public class Red implements Color {
    @Override
    public String fill() {
        return "Color is Red";
    }
}
```

When autowiring, you can do this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("red")
private Color red;
```

**EDIT**

---

When doing a constructor injection do the following:

```
@Autowired
public SomeClassConstructor(@Qualifier("red") Color red) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: How can I inject if I am using the constructor level injection instead?

Comment: Add `@Autowired` on the constructor and `@Qualifier` on the argument

Comment: It does not work as it throws the same exception on the Square class constructor as it again says Color reference to two different beans but only one is required.

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong. Can you please post a minimal verifiable code with stack trace

Comment: Apparently, I was missing the component scan on the application class, but after I have added that, still test cases are failing. Please take a look at the question as I have changed to be aligned with my test.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `@Qualifier` annotation in your services.
Then in your `@Autowired` you must reference them with the same annotation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers

```
@Service
@Qualifier("firstImplementation")
public class fistImplementation extends MyInterface {
 //doSomething
}

@Service
@Qualifier("secondImplementation")
public class secondImplementation extends MyInterface  { 
//doSomething
}


@Autowired
@Qualifier("firstImplementation") 
MyInterface myInterface;
```